# Are pre built lightning web components (example lightning-input) available for use in open source?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightninginput, open-source

I just tried using LWC on my local, but not able to use `<lightning-input />`. Is it available for open source? Is there any way to bring prebuilt lightning web components with `lightning` namespace to local?

Answer (score 2):

Currently no - none of the platform base component are available for off platform usage. Salesforce is targeting to open Source them in late July (#safeharbor) but their api / shape may also be slightly different than the known one due to missing Salesforce Service - will we see

For the 2nd Question - the only way as of today to use existing base components outside the platform would be via Lightning Out which is a different approach. I would wait those couple of months to see how its evolve with the LWC Framework

Comment: Or you can just write them by yourself, some of them are pretty easy to reproduce/reverse engineer (like lightning-input, button etc)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in a way they are available, checkout this npm to use base lightning component in your OSS LWC.
[Base Lightning Components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightning-base-components)

Also check this comment for details of how to get it installed

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/323644/55430