# Lightning Open source use of base components

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-oss

A few days back an npm package for base lightning components was released
[Base Lightning Components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightning-base-components)

With this I am expecting to use base lightning components like my favorite lightning-datatable in a node project.

But getting following error for adding Lightning Button

```
⚡⚡⚡⚡⚡  Lightning Web Components ⚡⚡⚡⚡⚡


�  Starting build process.
�  Local server listening: http://localhost:3001
× ｢wdm｣:
ERROR in ./src/modules/lightning/primitiveIcon/primitiveIcon.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@salesforce/i18n/dir' in 'E:\Temp Codes\lwc oss with base components\my-app\src\modules\lightning\primitiveIcon'
 @ ./src/modules/lightning/primitiveIcon/primitiveIcon.js 3:0-39 34:60-63
 @ ./src/modules/lightning/button/button.html
 @ ./src/modules/lightning/button/button.js
 @ ./src/modules/my/greeting/greeting.html
 @ ./src/modules/my/greeting/greeting.js
 @ ./src/modules/my/app/app.html
 @ ./src/modules/my/app/app.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/error-overlay-webpack-plugin/lib/entry-basic.js ./node_modules/error-overlay-webpack-plugin/lib/entry-devserver.js? ./src/index.js
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you are using the [create lwc app](https://github.com/muenzpraeger/create-lwc-app) to create the project scaffold.

There are a few things you need to make sure,

1. Make sure you have installed the lightning-base-components via npm install

   `npm install lightning-base-components`
2. Ensure that your lwc.config.json has the npm dependency specified

   ```
    {
      "modules": [
       {
          "dir": "src/modules"
       },
       { "npm": "lightning-base-components" }
     ]
   }
   ```
3. Make sure you install the SLDS using

   ```
    npm install @salesforce-ux/design-system --save-dev
   ```
4. Make sure you have lwc-services.config.js properly configured

   ```
     module.exports = {
      resources: [{ from: 'src/resources/', to: 'dist/resources/' },
      {
        from: 'node_modules/@salesforce-ux/design-system/assets',
        to: 'src/SLDS'
      },
     {
       from: 'node_modules/@salesforce-ux/design-system/assets',
       to: 'dist/SLDS'
      }
     ]
   };
   ```
5. Add the SLDS styles in your index.html at the head

   ```
   <link
       rel="stylesheet"
       href="/SLDS/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css"
   />
   ```

6. Make sure you have `import @lwc/synthetic-shadow` in your index.js.  Ensure the import is the first statement in your index.js file, else the synthetic shadow may not work

Comment: Hey @mohith Thanks for the reply! I was missing the npm dependency for lightning base component. But that still doesnt resolve the issue. Still getting "Module not found: \lightning-base-components\src\lightning\primitiveIcon" for lightning button

Comment: Also I get another dependency error for when i use Lightning-input. You can verify my package.json https://github.com/darkacer/SFDC-Extension-LWC

Comment: Did you run the npm install again and lwc build to generate the build.

Comment: Your build file does not look correct! npm run build will fix this

Comment: You mean lwc-services.config.js file? I am getting a successful build on running npm run build and code in the dist folder when i dont use any of the lightning base components. I have used one in queryBox.html.

Comment: This got resolved after updating lwc-services npm package.
Had to individually update every dependency to check

Comment: This works perfect, one addtion, related to point 6, ensure the import is the first statement in your index.js file, else the synthetic shadow does not work (for me).

Comment: not sure Mohit forgot or just wants us to work a little harder but there are single quotes in 
import '@lwc/synthetic-shadow';